# Lazy Load is not working even I force .include

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, lazy-loading, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to get a main table with 3 arrays of value, and it is not working at all. I have no idea how can I fix that, I am using the default get on controller:

```
public IEnumerable<SelfAssessment> GetSelfAssessment()
    {
        return _context.SelfAssessment;
    }
```

what I am trying to get on request:

```
    {
        "userEmail": "user@email.com",
        "createdAt": "2018-12-10T08:02:16.117",
        "update": false,
        "discomfort": [
        {
          "bodyPartId": 1,
          "intensityId": 1,
          "frequencyId": 1
        }
      ],
      "saanswers": [
        {
          "answerId": 1
        }
      ], 
      "sapostures": [
        {
          "postureAnswerId": 1,
          "postureId": 1,
        }
      ]
    }
```

And I am receiving this Json but with empty arrays as below:

```
   {
      "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
      "createdAt": "2018-12-10T08:02:16.117",
      "update": false,
      "discomfort": [],
      "saanswers": [],
      "sapostures": []
   }
```

This is my controller below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ErgoSAFE_API.Models;

namespace ErgoSAFE_API.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SelfAssessmentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ErgoSAFEContext _context;

    public SelfAssessmentsController(ErgoSAFEContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/SelfAssessments
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<SelfAssessment> GetSelfAssessment()
    {
        return _context.SelfAssessment;
    }

    // GET: api/SelfAssessments/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSelfAssessment([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var selfAssessment = await _context.SelfAssessment.FindAsync(id);

        if (selfAssessment == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(selfAssessment);
    }

    // PUT: api/SelfAssessments/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutSelfAssessment([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] SelfAssessment selfAssessment)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != selfAssessment.SelfAssessmentId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(selfAssessment).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!SelfAssessmentExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/SelfAssessments
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostSelfAssessment([FromBody] SelfAssessment selfAssessment)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.SelfAssessment.Add(selfAssessment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetSelfAssessment", new { id = selfAssessment.SelfAssessmentId }, selfAssessment);
    }

    // DELETE: api/SelfAssessments/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSelfAssessment([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var selfAssessment = await _context.SelfAssessment.FindAsync(id);
        if (selfAssessment == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.SelfAssessment.Remove(selfAssessment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(selfAssessment);
    }

    private bool SelfAssessmentExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.SelfAssessment.Any(e => e.SelfAssessmentId == id);
    }
}
}
```

.net core 2.1.403

Using VSCode, not Visual Studio

Edit 1:

```
        public IEnumerable<Object> Find (int id) {
        IQueryable<object> entryPoint = (from sa in _context.SelfAssessments
                          join a in _context.Answers on sa.SelfAssessmentId equals a.SelfAssessmentId
                          join q in _context.Questions on a.QuestionId equals q.QuestionId
                          where sa.SelfAssessmentId == id
                          select new {
                              SelfAssessmentID = sa.SelfAssessmentId,
                              Yearly = sa.Yearly,
                              Moved = sa.Moved,
                              CreatedAt = sa.CreatedAt,
                              Question = q.Description,
                              Value = a.Value
                          }).Take(10);
        List<object> result = entryPoint.ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

Edit 2:

I did some changes on my controller, when I debug the code, I can see that the value is coming, but there is no error when I try to return the result.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<SelfAssessment> GetSelfAssessment()
    {
        var qry = from s in _context.SelfAssessment
                  select s;

        var results = qry.Include("Discomfort").ToList();
        results = qry.Include("Sapostures").ToList();
        results = qry.Include("Saanswers").ToList();

        return results;
    }
```

Swagger results:

Code
Undocumented

Details
Error: OK

Responses

Code
200

Description
Success

Comment: Can you update code with  result.include()' and IQueryable attempts? And maybe you could narrow controller code to only GET method.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the .include anymore, just the IQueryable

Comment: there is no lazy loading when you are using select this way.

Comment: Well it actually works for me. In all places you use FindAsync in controllers is implementation different from just Find?

Comment: I found one thing, I am changing the topic again

Comment: Pleas try:

public IEnumerable<SelfAssessment> GetSelfAssessment()
{
    return _context.SelfAssessment.Include(x => x.Discomfort).Include(x => 
        x.Sapostures).Include(x => x.Saanswers).Tolist();
}

I think u have to add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; statement to use lambada version.

Comment: with your help I got different message, response body: can't parse JSON.  Raw result:

Comment: [{"selfAssessmentId":1,"userEmail":"oracy.martos@exxonmobil.com","createdAt":"2018-12-10T08:02:16.117","update":false,"profileEdguid":"12345678","contactContactDisplayName":"Oracy","contactContactTypeName":"Sup","contactPrimaryLanid":"omartos","contactContactPrimaryLanid":"Sup","locationBuildingCode":"SEC","locationBuildingName":"SEC","locationCityCode":"CTB","locationCityName":"Curitiba","locationCountryCode":"BR","locationCountryName":"Brazil","locationCountryStateCode":"PR","locationCountryStateName":"Parana","locationLocationName":"Sec","profileBirthDate":"2111",

Comment: "profileCommonName":"Oracy","profileDisplayName":"Martos, Oracy","profileFirstName":"Oracy","profileIdentityStatusName":"Oracy","profileIsPrimary":true,"profileLastName":"Martos","profileMiddleName":null,"profilePrimaryLanid":"omartos","profilePrimarySmtp":"oracy.martos","profileFormOfAddressName":"xxx","workDetailAdminWorkerTypeName":"xxx","workDetailDisplayName":"xxx","workDetailDoag":7,"workDetailIsOnLegalHold":false,"workDetailIsSupervisor":false,"workDetailIsVip":true,"workDetailJobTitle":"xxx","workDetailPrimaryLanid":"xxx","discomfort":

Comment: [{"id":1,"selfAssessmentId":1,"bodyPartId":1,"intensityId":1,"frequencyId":1,"bodyPart":null,"frequency":null,"intensity":null

Comment: "discomfort:[{"id":1,"selfAssessmentId":1,"bodyPartId":1,"intensityId":1,"frequencyId":1,"bodyPart":null,"frequency":null,"intensity":null
It is not bringing all data

Comment: I'll post possible solution in answer because it might take some place.

Answer (score 1):

So if the problem is not complete data the solution should be easy.
I think you have to eager load also nested properties.

If your model is:

```
    public class MainEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ICollection<MiddleEntity> MiddleEntities { get; set; }
        //Other properties...
    }

    public class MiddleEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MainEntityId { get; set; }
        public MainEntity MainEntity { get; set; }

        ICollection<InnerEntity> InnerEntities { get; set; }
        //Other properties...
    }

    public class InnerEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MiddleEntityId { get; set; }
        public MiddleEntity MiddleEntity { get; set; }
        //Other properties...
    }
```

The solution should be:

```
    [HttpGet("{Id}")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MainEntity>> GetMainEntities(int Id)
    {
        var result = _context.MainEtities
            .Include(x => x.MiddleEntities)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.InnerEntities)
            .ToList();

        return Ok(result);
    }
```